# How can you take an HTML input and pass that as an argument into a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Right now, I am trying to create an application that takes a zip code as an input and returns the closest location to that person. The problem I am having is being able to take the input in as the argument in my Javascript function. Here's a piece of the application:

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
  zipCode()
};
// Zip Code locator 
const zipCode = (input) => {
  // Makes sure zip code is 5 numbers long
  if (input.length !== 5) {
    return 'Please enter a valid 5 digit zipcode';
  }
  if (input.slice(0, 2) === '06') {
    return 'Your closest location is in CT.';
  } else if (input.slice(0, 2) === '01') {
    return 'Your closest location is in MA';
  } else {
    return 'No location found';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your zip code:</p>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="zipCode()">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `zipCode(ReferenceTheInputValueHere)` It would help if you gave your input an id so you can look it up easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value` to get the value of the input element.

Also, the function should do something with the return value, such as display it in an alert. And to prevent the form from submitting and reloading the page, it should return `false`.

You shouldn't add the handler with both `onsubmit` in the HTML and assigning to `onsubmit` in JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").innerText = zipCode(document.getElementById("zip").value);
  return false;
};
// Zip Code locator 
const zipCode = (input) => {
  // Makes sure zip code is 5 numbers long
  if (input.length !== 5) {
    return 'Please enter a valid 5 digit zipcode';
  }
  if (input.slice(0, 2) === '06') {
    return 'Your closest location is in CT.';
  } else if (input.slice(0, 2) === '01') {
    return 'Your closest location is in MA';
  } else {
    return 'No location found';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your zip code:</p>
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="zip" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway I can do this without an alert? I was hoping that after the form was submitted, the answer would populate there instead of as an alert.

Comment: That was just example code. You can do anything you want with the return value.

Comment: I've updated the example to put the value in a DIV.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add an `id` to your input.

then you can use `document.getElementById`

```js
let input = document.getElementById('zipcode');
// Zip Code locator 
const zipCode = () => {
  // Makes sure zip code is 5 numbers long
  if (input.length !== 5) {
    return 'Please enter a valid 5 digit zipcode';
  }
  if (input.slice(0, 2) === '06') {
    return 'Your closest location is in CT.';
  } else if (input.slice(0, 2) === '01') {
    return 'Your closest location is in MA';
  } else {
    return 'No location found';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your zip code:</p>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="zipCode()">
  <input type="text" id="zipcode">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```